# Synchronized non-local CharacterController's velocity is stuck at the last movement in Unity3D

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

I have `CharacterControllers` as players in my **multiplayer** scene, and they got `NetworkTransforms` attached, with

- `Sync Mode = Sync Character Controller`.

When I **stop running** with my character, my character **stops on the other players' screens as well**.

I've got `MonoBehaviours` attached to them, where I control the character's animations based on `characterController.velocity`.

**The problem is this:**

The **animations won't stop** because `characterController.velocity` is the **same as it was when I was running**.

This only occurs on **non-local** characters, because the local player got `Local Player Authority` checked, so its controller isn't synced *from* the server but *to* the server.

Why and how could I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to send `characterController.velocity` ?

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but that's just a workaround, not really an explanation or correct solution :\

Comment: can you update your question and add your scripts and insert gif or video that show the problem.

Comment: can you upload a sample I need it for testing purposes

Comment: Just create a character controller, sync them across the network, log their velocity and see that even if they aren't moving anymore, their velocity stays as it was during moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an issue originating from **Unity's network code**, so after a few failed tries, I just fixed it by **calculating the velocity locally**.